# Webcam Application stops working after a random time

Tags: android, service, webcam, photo, intentservice

I'm sorry if I got basic mistake or something like that in my program, but I#m pretty new to Android.
I created an Application to take a Photo after a given time, store it and Upload it to a Server then. I used a BackgroundService for the Upload but I am not really sure if it's created correct. 
The Problem is that the Application always shuts down after a Random time and i can't figure out why this is happening. Would be really happy about some ideas or suggestions how to solve this, thanks!

My Timer

```
public void timedWebcam()
{


Timer myTimer = new Timer();
//Initialize the Timer Task
WebcamTimer webcamTimer = new WebcamTimer();
    if(intervall != 0)
    {
        //Starting the Timer
        myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(webcamTimer, 0, 60000*intervall);
    }
    else 
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "interval not set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
        }
}
```

WebcamTimer

```
    private class WebcamTimer extends TimerTask 
{

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {           
                Date date = new Date();
                Calendar calendar = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
                calendar.setTime(date);
                actualHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

                System.out.println("Actual Hour= "+actualHour);
                System.out.println("Start Time= "+startTime);
                System.out.println("Stop Time= "+stopTime);

                if( (actualHour >= startTime) && (actualHour < stopTime) )
                {
                    takePhoto(); //Takes the Picture
                    uploadToFTP(); //Uploads taken Picture to FTP
                }   
                else 
                {
                     nightMode();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The service call

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,UploadService.class);
    this.startService(intent);
```

Finally the UploadService class

```
public class UploadService extends IntentService 
{



   //Server Properties
    public String server = "sample.aon.at";
    public int port = addPort;
    public String user = "user";
    public String pass = "password";

FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();

public UploadService() 
{        
    super("UploadService");    
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) 
{
     // For each start request, send a message to start a job and deliver the
    // start ID so we know which request we're stopping when we finish the job                                  
                try 
                {

                    ftpClient.connect(server, port);
                    ftpClient.login(user, pass);
                    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

                    ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                    ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory("webcam");

                    // uploads file using an InputStream
                    File firstLocalFile = new File(MainActivity.path);
                    System.out.println("Path used for upload: "+MainActivity.path);

                    String firstRemoteFile = "webcam.jpg";
                    InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(firstLocalFile);

                    boolean done = ftpClient.storeFile(firstRemoteFile, inputStream);
                    inputStream.close();
                    if (done)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Upload finished");      
                    }

                } 
                catch (IOException ex) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                } 
               finally 
                {
                    try {
                        if (ftpClient.isConnected()) 
                        {
                            ftpClient.logout();
                            ftpClient.disconnect();
                            stopSelf();
                        }
                    } 
                    catch (IOException ex) 
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


}
```

Comment: are u testing this on emulator or a real device. I wouldn't trust an emulator to give correct feedback on any camera related app

Comment: At the moment I am testing on Samsung Galaxy S4 but at the end it should work for HTC Legend (Lowest Android Version is set)

Answer (score 0):

I will try to put the timer instance in your upper handler class. I am not sure but I guess if you instantiated the Timer object inside a method this reference will be destroyed after the method closes. Then later the (GC)Garbage Collector will kill all the resources that were given to the timer instance when created.

So create the timer instance from the upper class and just call timer.schedule(...) inside the method.